# Can't seem to get rid of NonUniqueObjectException

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, orm

I am using SINGLE_TABLE inheritance strategy in Java Hibernate, here is the setup:

```
Class A

 @Cascade(CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN, CascadeType.ALL)
 List<B> Bs;
```

B has a sublcass Ba that extends B. Ba has one extra field that B does not have. The reason I am doing it this way is only Ba objects (which are far fewer) should care about this extra field and I want to avoid the overhead of having it on every B object.

During a save, the way our setup is, we have to update the former B objects fields (rather than just changing references). So we can't do List of Bs = List of Changed Bs, we have to find each individual B by primary key and update the fields, so like B.fields = changedB.fields

The times when this exception occurs is during save, when a former B object needs to be saved as a Ba with the extra field. The reverse direction (saving a former Ba object to a B) is fine I can just set that extra field to null or cast down. But I can't seem to find a way to turn a B object into a Ba.

I've tried

- Removing the B from the list and adding a Ba before the save, that is when I get this exception.
- I also tried even swapping all the fields from the B to the Ba that needs to be turned into a B and vice-verca, but that also didn't work and I got an exception because I changed the Pk of these objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During [Session flush the DML operation order](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-knowing-flush-operations-order-matters/) is:

- inserts
- updates
- deletions of collections elements
- inserts of the collection elements
- deletes

So, even if you remove the element and add a new one, the insert will run before the delete, hence throwing the constraint violation exception.

To make it work, you need to manually flush, after the remove and before you add the new element back into the children collection:

```
a.removeChild(b);
session.flush();
a.addChild(ba);
```

The remove/addChild are utilities setting both sides of the bi-directional association, if that's the case in your domain model.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have session context in the part of the code I am doing this. The place I'm doing this is simple setting a new list of the collection to the old list so hibernate can save the new one. Is there no other way I can set a B object to a Ba (with the extra field) then? I mean I just need to add an extra value to a field I know exists in the database (and child class) but not on the object itself.

Comment: Reassigning a new collection is going to remove all children and add the new objects. This is not efficient and in your case not effective either. It leads to inserts first and deletes later. So you need to push the logic where you have the Session.